# undefined method `alias_example_to' for RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to use `remarkable_activerecord-4.0.0.alpha4` with `rspec-2.7.1` and `rails-3.0.7`. As of now, I haven't used it any example. I have just added it to the Gemfile and did a `bundle install`. I am using spork to load the application behorehand. When I run spork, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `alias_example_to' for RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup:Class (NoMethodError)
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/core/rspec.rb:26:in `<class:ExampleGroup>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/core/rspec.rb:13:in `<module:Core>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/core/rspec.rb:12:in `<module:RSpec>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/core/rspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/core.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable_activemodel-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/active_model.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/remarkable_activerecord-4.0.0.alpha4/lib/remarkable/active_record.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/chandranshu/work/pep/data_entry/branches/ws_chan_r2_test_cases/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in preload'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:8:in `preload'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
```

I have looked in the `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` and the `alias_example_to` method is present there. How should I go about debugging this?

**Update**

After reading a related post, I edited the file in question to explicitly load rspec and it started working fine. Immediately, I realized that the order of `require 'rspec/rails'` and `require 'remarkable/active_record'` statements in my spec_helper was wrong. Corrected that and it worked immediately.

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the edited question body in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> **Update** After reading a related post, I edited the file in question to explicitly load rspec and it started working fine. Immediately, I realized that the order of `require 'rspec/rails'` and `require 'remarkable/active_record'` statements in my spec_helper was wrong. Corrected that and it worked immediately.

~ answer per [Chandranshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563535/chandranshu)